# Searching for a string in an executable's memory from an injected dll

Tags: c++, windows

The title explains my goal very well, it should be simple but my solution just doesn't seem to be functioning properly. Currently, the function always returns NULL. When I use another program to locate the string and manually point memcmp to it, it returns 0 as it should.

```
DWORD findString(const char *input)
{
    DWORD address;
    size_t length = strlen(input);
    DWORD baseAddress = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    DWORD maxAddress = (baseAddress + 26480640)-length;//the large # is the approximate size of the base module of the executable
    for (address = baseAddress; address < maxAddress; address++)
    {
        if (memcmp(input, (void *)address, length) == 0)
        {
            return address;
        }
    }
    OutputDebugStringA("String not found!");
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Does `memcmp` get called?

Comment: What is the value of `length`?

Comment: Also, you might not need to inject a DLL - see `ReadProcessMemory`.

Comment: @immibis It varies depending on the argument obviously, but with the string I'm searching for, it is 45.

Comment: Also, is this 64-bit code?

Comment: @immibis It is 32 bit code.

Comment: @hyde Actually, it seems as though it is being called.